# ATMega32 USBasp not programming

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, avrdude, usbasp

I use no Arduino just trying to program a simple ATMega32 using USBASP. Getting this message:

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

---

**Explanation:**

I use an AVR development board with 8.00:

[image: AVR developement board]

To make the AVR model label more clear, I have made this photo as well ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCaMm.jpg))

To program the microcontroller, I use a USBASP. The crystal of the programmer is 12.0 MHz (though might not be relevant).

[image: USBASP programmer]

I installed `Avrdude` on ubuntu and wrote the following program:

```
// main.c

#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {

 DDRD = 255;
 PORTD=255;

 DDRC = 255;

 while(1){

 PORTC=255;
 _delay_ms(200);

 PORTC=0;
 _delay_ms(200);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Then compiled and made hex file:

```
avr-gcc -w -Os -DF_CPU=8000000UL -mmcu=atmega32 -c -o main.o main.c
avr-gcc -w -mmcu=atmega32 main.o -o main
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom main main.hex
```

Till now `main.hex` file is created successfully.

Then, trying to load it into microcontroller:

```
sudo avrdude -p m32 -c usbasp -B 8 -v -e -u -U flash:w:main.hex
```

And the output is disappointing. I mean the last part:

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The full message is:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/me/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbasp
         Setting bit clk period        : 100.0
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom         4    10    64    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
           flash         33     6    64    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : usbasp
         Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

avrdude: set SCK frequency to 8000 Hz
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: set SCK frequency to 8000 Hz
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: reading input file "main.hex"
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (162 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.15s

avrdude: 162 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against main.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file main.hex:
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file main.hex contains 162 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.10s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0x0c
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Here is the way I have connected the microcontroller while downloading the `hex` file:

[image: Downloading hex file]

When I check the communication, it seems to be alright:

```
sudo avrdude -p m32 -c usbasp -t
```

The response:

```
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502
avrdude>
```

So what is wrong? What to do?

---

It seems nothing is programmed. I checked it with a 5VDC adaptor ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrzl1.jpg)) and a breadboard with LED and capacitor. Connecting LED to VCC turns it on ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhsW.jpg)) which shows LED is working. Connecting to any pin of port D does not turn on the LED ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USaeo.jpg)) connecting to some pins of port C turn on the LED ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnFsq.jpg)) and some don't ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRsms.jpg)). But there is no blink. Note that I am using a virgin ATMega32 chip.

---

**Update**

Inspired from [this](https://www.das-labor.org/wiki/Borg16) website (btw, I dont know German!) and a few others, finally I used the following command:

```
sudo avrdude -p m32 -c usbasp -v -b 19200 -B5 -e -U flash:w:main.hex -U lfuse:w:0xe4:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m
```

Response:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/me/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping
     Using Port                    : usb
     Using Programmer              : usbasp
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
     Setting bit clk period        : 5.0
     AVR Part                      : ATmega32
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PA0
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom         4    10    64    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
       flash         33     6    64    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  2000  2000 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          4    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : usbasp
     Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

avrdude: set SCK frequency to 187500 Hz
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as E4
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 99
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: set SCK frequency to 187500 Hz
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: reading input file "main.hex"
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (162 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.11s

avrdude: 162 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against main.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file main.hex:
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file main.hex contains 162 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.07s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 162 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: reading input file "0xe4"
avrdude: writing lfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse written
avrdude: verifying lfuse memory against 0xe4:
avrdude: load data lfuse data from input file 0xe4:
avrdude: input file 0xe4 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip lfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of lfuse verified
avrdude: reading input file "0x99"
avrdude: writing hfuse (1 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse written
avrdude: verifying hfuse memory against 0x99:
avrdude: load data hfuse data from input file 0x99:
avrdude: input file 0x99 contains 1 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip hfuse data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1 bytes of hfuse verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as E4
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as 99
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:FF, E:99, L:E4)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Seems it works!!!

Now, all pins on `portD` turn on the LED bright and pin `C0`, `C1`, `C6` and `C7` blink bright while `C2`, `C3`, `C5` give dim but constant light to LED and `C4` does not turn on the LED at all.

Though, I am very happy of writing something into the chip, could someone explain what has happened?

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem was in baud rate.
"-b 19200" was the solution.

A promt was in line:
"avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update."

Comment: The baud rate setting does nothing with USBasp, as far as I am aware. The USBasp is a usb device, and does not use a usb to serial converter internally. The same applies to `-B`, which sets the bitrate but works with the Atmel JTAG ICE only. For lowering the data rate with a USBasp, there should be a jumper or solder pad that you need to short out if the target clock frequency is too low (< ~2MHz).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and changing the lfuse to E4 fixed it!  I think 1Mhz may be too slow for the programmer and setting to 8Mhz internal fixes it.